# Executing a method in a dart TextField on every key press

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `TextField` in my project, which will be used to act as an autocomplete text field. I need it to respond to key presses.

After researching on Flutter's documentation, https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes, I found two ways of allowing a `TextField` to execute a method every time the `TextField`'s text changed, however it only executes that method when you hit and enter and leave the focus of the `TextField`

I have used both the `controller` method, and the `onChanged` method and neither work.

Is there a way of having a `TextField` respond to *every* key press, as you type in a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnChanged should work fine.  If you are trying to change something on the screen you will have to make a call to setState() and your functionality with in that call.

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I didn't remember that. Thank you for your help

Comment: If the TextField is empty and i want to detect a backspace pressed on an empty TextField, is that possible ?

Comment: @FemnDharamshi I'm not sure if that is possible. Think the best way to go about that would be levering a TextEditingController.  Checkout this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14809 I haven't had time to test any of these suggestions.